# TX packet and TX byte count zero in ifconfig output

Tags: linux, networking

I wonder how is it possible to achieve such configuration that no TX bytes and packets are ever counted? 
There is substantial amount of traffic on loopback interface though.
The server runs RHEL 6 and uses two 10Gb ethernet interfaces in 802.3ad bonding configuration. It is a NFS client and application server with moderate network traffic.

Uptime

```
$ uptime
11:12:14 up 127 days, 22:20,  2 users,  load average: 7.86, 8.31, 7.14
```

Interface statistics

```
$ ifconfig
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:yy:de:ad:be:ef
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1602:ecff:fe6c:6248/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78754933233 errors:12 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:12
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:83417317310129 (75.8 TiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

eth8      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:yy:de:ad:be:ef
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56120366224 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:60876314731840 (55.3 TiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

eth10     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:yy:de:ad:be:ef
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22634567048 errors:9 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:9
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:22541002608976 (20.5 TiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:968312148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:968312148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14257112447341 (12.9 TiB)  TX bytes:14257112447341 (12.9 TiB)
```

bonding configuration

```
$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
    Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

    Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
    Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
    MII Status: up
    MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
    Up Delay (ms): 0
    Down Delay (ms): 0

    802.3ad info
    LACP rate: fast
    Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
    Active Aggregator Info:
            Aggregator ID: 2
            Number of ports: 2
            Actor Key: 33
            Partner Key: 33873
            Partner Mac Address: xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc

    Slave Interface: eth10
    MII Status: up
    Speed: 10000 Mbps
    Duplex: full
    Link Failure Count: 1
    Permanent HW addr: xx:yy:de:ad:be:ef
    Aggregator ID: 2
    Slave queue ID: 0

    Slave Interface: eth8
    MII Status: up
    Speed: 10000 Mbps
    Duplex: full
    Link Failure Count: 2
    Permanent HW addr: xx:yy:de:ad:be:af
    Aggregator ID: 2
    Slave queue ID: 0
```

Comment: looks like a driver bug, which network adapter, driver and kernel version?

Comment: It could be. I see this on all hosts with RHEL 6.6, kernel 2.6.32-504 and **ixgbe** RHEL stock driver version 3.19.1-k. The only host with RHEL 6.4, kernel 2.6.32-358 and **ixgbe** driver version 3.9.15-k shows proper TX values.

Comment: Sounds like you have answered your own question. I have seen this in other Linux kernels, specifically when bonding interfaces via 802.3ad